# What is the activation energy barrier of uncatalyzed nitrogen fixation?

Tags: kinetics, energy, reference-request

I'm interested in the activation energy ($E_\mathrm a$) of uncatalyzed aqueous nitrogen fixation:
$$\ce{3 H2 + N2 -> 2 NH3}$$
Biology performs this reaction with the nitrogenase enzyme at room temperature. Humans have come up with ways of doing this reaction with a metal catalyst like rubidium at ~300 °C. I am not interested in the activation energy of nitrogen fixation when catalyzed by biology or by industrial chemists. I want to know the activation energy of the **uncatalyzed** reaction.

The most luck I have had is with a book titled "Ammonia: Principles and Industrial Practice", which states, "According to estimates[99], the homogenous reaction of nitrogen with hydrogen to form ammonia in the gas phase requires an activation energy of 230–420 kJ/mol." Reference [99] is cited as "W. G. Frankenburger, Catalysis 1954-1960 3 (1955) 171" which I haven't found a copy of yet. I would prefer to have a measured (not estimated) value that is a bit more precise.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: For an activation energy, you first need a sensible mechanism under some defined conditions. I don't think there is one. The thermal decomposition is sure to take another route. You can of course make assumptions, but I strongly doubt the number has any scientific value. Sorry. I'd be glad to get convinced of the opposite.

Comment: Side note: 400 kJ/mol is equivalent to a temperature of about 50 kK. That's right, *kilo Kelvin*.

Comment: @Karl I understand what you mean that a specific mechanism is needed to define an activation energy. I'm not sure what the mechanism would be. I would imagine though that at ~2000 K it would still be thermodynamically favorable for nitrogen and hydrogen to make a fair bit of ammonia, and some small fraction of the molecules that have enough energy would react via some mechanism. I am interested in the activation energy of that scenario.

Comment: I think the point is you *won't* get any ammonia *at all*. You'd need a three- or four-particle reaction, and if those 400kJ/mol are anywhere near a realistic value, at 2000K you will get just nothing. I'm sure you could do it at extreme pressures, but that's likely a different reaction then.

Comment: What are you actually interested in, i.e. why are you asking this? The number itself seems not so terribly interesting, perhaps we can string up sth. else?

Comment: @Karl I'm interested in the rate enhancement of the nitrogenase enzyme complex, and a bunch of other other enzymes. There are cool papers like [this one](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/cr050311y) which show the rate enhancement of a bunch of enzymes. The paper linked doesn't describe the rate enhancement of some of the oldest enzymes like nitrogenase or the enzymes in methanogens or CO consumers. I would really like to know how effective these old enzymes are at speeding up chemical reactions, and what kinetic barriers they had to overcome.

Comment: Sorry, but that number is just pointless. The uncatalysed reaction *does not take place*, period. Comparing different catalysts, or different mechanical pathways is one thing. What you want to do however, is, citing E. Rutherford, *stamp collecting*. ;-)

Comment: @Karl haha, well maybe we can agree to disagree. I think understanding how life has been able to overcome certain kinetic barriers is interesting, and not just stamp collecting. By "that number" do you mean rate enhancement? and in your earlier comment you said "at 2000K you will get just nothing". what you mean by "nothing?"

Comment: *Agree to disagree* is a good solution to many discussions. ;-) I mean no ammonia. You cited those 400 kJ/mol. That is equivalent to a temperature of around* fiftythousand* Kelvin. http://www.colby.edu/chemistry/PChem/Hartree.html 400 kJ/mol, or 4 electronvolts, are just not available in chemistry. And once you have reached that transition state, you'd need to get rid of this huge amount of energy again. And you just can't, says I.

Comment: *know how effective these old enzymes are at speeding up chemical reactions,* there's the problem. The reaction with the enzyme is a *totally* different reaction than the hypothetic uncatalysed one.

Comment: You say that 400 kJ.mol is equivalent to a temperature of around 5e4 kelvin. This doesn't make sense. Temperature is a measure of the distribution of kinetic energy in a material. In this image [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14qPaBahr0BS0mGrf9hG_zHbF2rXutCHe/view?usp=sharing) I plotted the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution for 2000K and 50,000 kelvin (so we are talking about an ideal gas). Your are right in saying that the average kinetic energy of a mole of N2 at 50,000 K is ~400 kJ/mol but the average kinetic energy isn't the most crucial bit of information...

Comment: Even at 2000K, there will be a 1e-10 chance (integrate 2000k curve from dotted line to $\infty$) that a N2 molecule will have sufficient energy to overcome the 400 kJ/mol activation energy barrier. 1e-10 chance means out of a mol of molecules ~6e13 molecules will have enough energy to overcome the activation energy barrier. So this activation energy is surmountable at "lower" temperatures.

Comment: @Karl I understand what you mean about the enzyme doing a completely different reaction than the uncatalyzed reaction. It may feel like comparing apples to oranges.